# php Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: php, ftp, cross-domain

i am having problems with my ftp/php cross domain requests. With my browser i can access the contents, by passing an argument like this: http://xxx.org/models/get.php?file=default_app/y_car_new/stock.jpg . But with JavaScript the same link gives me Origin `http://localhost:8000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`
i already tried

> header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *")

with no luck on the following script. I have a get.php file in my ftp access only server with the following code:

```
<?

if(isset($_GET["file"])) {
    $filepath = "/.../models/".$_GET["file"];
    //echo "path: " , $filepath;
    $filetype = pathinfo($filepath);
    //echo $filetype['extension'], "\n";
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Content-Type: '.$filetype['extension']);
    // //header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
    ob_clean();

    readfile($filepath);
}//if

else {
   echo '<img src="http://stupidbadmemes.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/no-you-may-not.jpg"></img>';
}


?>
```

what am i doing wrong in this script?

Comment: Sending a cross-origin header along with a response is kinda pointless. It's like granting permission to access a bank vault by writing it on a note stored in the vault. Can't get into the vault because you don't have the note saying you can go in, and you can't get the note because it's locked inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try opening up your Access control a bit more if your going to be sending GET data back and forth. Same Origin rules can be very picky.

Allow-Origin manages which servers can make requests.

Max-Age implements an expiration.

Allow-Methods allows the requester to send GET/POST/etc. data to you.

**Here's an example:**

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 3628800');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
```

**Side Notes**

Allow-Origin should be set to your specific requesting domains when in production the * adds some risk there.

Please look into sanitizing your input, accessing files like this is a risky thing to do. You essentially opening up people to read any files in your working directory.

`$filepath = "/.../models/".$_GET["file"];`

Comment: i understand those risks but for now i just need it working..
anyways i tried adding that to the script and it still does not work

Comment: Any file on your system, in fact, not just ones in the current directory. Consider `file=../../../../etc/passwd`!

Comment: i think that your answer started working... i didnt change anything though... i will keep testing a bit more and mark ur answer as the correct one

Answer (score 0):

This is a client side "problem". It's rather a security concern that is implemented by browsers to disallow requests from one domain to another. There are ways around this, notably JSONP.

Comment: i had this working before, although i didn't write the other script. the problem is that i accidently deleted it and now i am trying to rewrite it..

Comment: the content i need to return includes images and XML. can i use jsonP to get xml content?